# Edge is not allowing vue.js to work as a module from asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, vuejs2, microsoft-edge, es6-modules

I have a created this minimal reproduction that best represents my setup:

_emptyLayout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon"
          type="image/png"
          href="/Content/images/favicon.ico" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

DataController.cs

```
[Authorize(Users = "DataReader")]
public class DataController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult windex()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

windex.cshtml

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "windex";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_emptyLayout.cshtml";
}

<h2>windex</h2>
<div id="app">
    {{msg}}
</div>
<script src="~/Scripts/data.js" type="module"></script>
```

data.js

```
import Vue from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.esm.browser.js'

export default new Vue(
    {
        el: '#app',
        data: {msg:'hi there'}
    });
```

Basically, when Edge renders the page I see "{{msg}}". When Firefox renders the page I see "hi there".

There are no error messages or warnings.

The problem doesn't seem to exist for plain html pages. For example I tried to replicate the issue using stack snippets, but Edge shows "hi there".

Also, it renders fine in Edge if I'm not using modules, just regular script tags.

Has anyone encountered this issue with this combination of technologies before? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: It can be possible that some security related settings in Internet options cause this issue because you are accessing that file from another domain. If possible for you than can try to download the file and try to include it in your project folder and than again make a test? Also try to lower down the security settings of internet options and make a test. Open the site in IE to check whether it also shows the similar output or not. It can help to narrow down the issue.